# Making a responsive word box

Tags: css, text, responsive-design

Sorry for the weird title, but I am not aware of a name or simple way to put what I am trying to achieve.
I want to make something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gt07.png), but I want it to be responsive so that if some words are longer, the other words get bigger, and the aspect ratio (and shape) of the div remains the same.

I made the [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gt07.png) in Adobe XD, but I would like to recreate it in css.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you please provide examples of what you've tried to this point? The goal of SO is to help you improve, not to simply write code for you.

Comment: @BryceHowitson I literally don't even know how to begin about solving this. I understand that this is not the purpose of SO, and I really don't like asking people to help me out like this, but I don't even know what the thing I want to do is called.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking for help. Why don't you start with adding some HTML to your question with real or example content? I don't think that specific layout is "called" anything. However, text in a specific layout regardless of the size is called a "Typographic Lockup" so you might want to start there.

Comment: This is a really helpful article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) is probably best for this. How responsive it will be will depend on how well you write your media queries.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0;
  grid-column-gap: 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 69px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #3D3D3D;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: start;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one {
  color: #40C894;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.two {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.three {
grid-row: 3;
  color: #8A8A8A;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.four {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
  color: #8A8A8A;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.five {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.six {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  color: #8A8A8A;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="one">38 K</div>
  <div class="two">19 D</div>
  <div class="three">6037</div>
  <div class="four">DMG</div>
  <div class="five">6 MVPs</div>
  <div class="six">2K/D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was experimenting with the css grid too right now, but you already did it. Thank you so much!

Comment: In my opinion, CSS Grid is the best option for CSS layouts. Especially with stuff like you're wanting to do.